Domain shift when the inside function is scaled and translated
I've been playing around with circular functions and finding solutions to those in preparation for an upcoming test. For example: $$\sin(2x) = 0.5, x \in [-\pi, \pi]$$
For this particular equation, as the $x$ is scaled inside by $2$, the domain of $[-\pi, \pi]$ therefore has to be expanded to encompass values that would be not have been considered before into $[-2\pi, 2\pi]$.
However, I fell apart when dealing with horizontal shift: $$\sin\left(2x + \frac{\pi}{3}\right) = 0.5, x \in [-\pi, \pi]$$
First of all, I asked my Math teacher if the domain would change with this new addition, but she said "none". This baffled me as there surely would be a change as if the function was instead $\sin(2x + 1000) = 0.5$ the domain would sure have changed to take into account values far, far away.
When solving $\sin\left(2x + \frac{\pi}{3}\right) = 0.5$, one would take the inverse sine, then first subtract $\frac{\pi}{3}$, then dividing $2$, so I thought the domain would be changed into $\left[2(-\pi + \frac{\pi}{3}), 2(\pi + \frac{\pi}{3})\right]$, adding $\frac{\pi}{3}$ instead of subtracting to cancel the effect of subtracting it later in the solving process.
Naturally, I went on Desmos to find a visual representation of what I'm trying to figure out, but I found out that multiplying the brackets expanded the domain too much? This makes no sense to me at all, as the scaling came later.
I've been struggling to wrap my head around this concept for a few hours, it would be great for someone to confirm which of the following is the correct way:
$$\sin(ax + b), x \in [c,d]$$
$$1. \therefore ax + b \in [a(c + b), a(d + b)]$$
$$OR$$
$$2. \therefore ax + b \in [ac + b, ad + b]$$
I'd love to get an explanation to why that expansion is correct. Understanding this will also help me use it in more general questions to such as $f(a \cdot g(x) + b)$ thank you very much!

Do you mean range of the argument of sine instead of domain as in domain of $\sin 2x$ for $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$ should be $[-2\pi,2\pi]$?

I don't think so? I'm looking for how the domain of the argument changes to take additional into account. I'm pretty sure the range has nothing to do with this?

I mean to say that you have mentioned the domain of $\sin 2x$, $x\in [-\pi,\pi]$ must be extended to $[-2\pi,2\pi]$, do you mean range of the argument, i.e., $2x$?

The second result is true, since if $x\in[c,d]\implies ax\in[ac, ad]\implies ax+b\in[ac+b, ad+b]$. For the case $a.g(x)+b$ that you've mentioned, this method can be applied if $g(x)$ is montonic for $x\in[c,d]$.

Oh right, that makes sense sorry. Yes, I meant the range of the argument $2x$.

I suppose that makes sense, I wasn't too sure how manipulating the part on the left could affect the right.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

After discussing with @Math Guy, I finally understood where I've gone wrong! I leave this answer here to hopefully help any person struggling to wrap their heads around with the same problem:
$$\sin(2x+\frac{\pi}{3}), x\in[-\pi,\pi]$$
By saying that I was finding the "domain" of argument of the above function was greatly misleading to myself, and is probably the reason why I was so confused.
In my head, I was trying to find:
Let $u = 2x+\frac{\pi}{3}$, what is the domain of $\sin(u)$ for $x\in[-\pi,\pi]$?
What I should've been thinking about is the range. If $x$ can be anywhere from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, the range of $2x+\frac{\pi}{3}$ would therefore be $[2\cdot(-\pi)+\frac{\pi}{3}, 2\pi+\frac{\pi}{3}]$, simple! Think of it like this: the function $\sin(x),x\in[-\pi,\pi]$ takes in numbers which lie in the range of the argument, in this case: the range of $x$, $[-\pi,\pi]$. By altering the argument to $2x+\frac{\pi}{3}$, it still holds, and $\sin$ takes in whatever the range of $2x+\frac{\pi}{3}$ is.
In general, this worked because $ax+b$ was montonic, meaning the gradient of it does not change sign. Let's have a look at a general form:
$$f(a\cdot g(x) + b),x\in[c,d]$$
The range of $a\cdot g(x) + b$ will only definitely be $[ac+b, ad+b]$ if $g(x)$ was montonic, and $ac+b < ad+b$. If for example, the argument was $-2x$ (meaning its gradient is negative $\therefore$ it's decreasing) we would switch it around to $[ad+b, ac+b]$, as now $ad+b<ac+b$. This means for non-montonic $g(x)$'s we will have to find the range on the side, instead of multiplying $a$ and adding $b$ willy-nilly.
I hope someone found this helpful! I certainly did, now that I know how to explain it myself. Big thanks to @Math Guy again!
